# How to pair hosts with variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory like:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    server_group1:
      hosts:
        host1:
    server_group2:
      children:
        app1:
          hosts:
            host2:
            host3:
        app2:
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
    server_group3:
...
```

I have organized my server variables like so:

- `group_vars/server_group2/app1`

  ```yaml
  app1:
    name1: value1
    name2: value2
  ```
- `group_vars/server_group2/app2`

  ```yaml
  app2:
    name1: value11
    name2: value21
  ```

I am trying to name my dict after the group (thus making them unique) and access it in my playbook:

```yaml
hosts: server_group2
tasks:
  - name: check file
    local_action: stat path=path/to/test/{{hostvars[0].name1}}
    register: payld_txt

  - name: conditional transfer
    copy:
      src: path/to/test/{{hostvars[0].name1}}
      dest: /svr/path/{{hostvars[0].name2}}
    when: payld_txt.stat.exists
```

I end up with this error:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'name1' is undefined

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Before you go any further, you need to fix your inventory which does not respect ansible's structure for yaml sources. A simple command as the following can give you some hints:

```
$ ansible -i inventories/test.yml all --list-hosts
 [WARNING]: Skipping unexpected key (server_group1) in group (all), only "vars", "children" and "hosts" are valid

 [WARNING]: Skipping unexpected key (server_group2) in group (all), only "vars", "children" and "hosts" are valid

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

  hosts (0):
```

The correct syntax is:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    server_group1:
      hosts:
        host1:
    server_group2:
      children:
        app1:
          hosts:
            host2:
            host3:
        app2:
          hosts:
            host4:
            host5:
```

Which now gives:

```
$ ansible -i inventories/test.yml all --list-hosts
  hosts (5):
    host1
    host2
    host3
    host4
    host5
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a copying error. Correcting the question.

Comment: Your inventory still has errors. You need the `hosts:` declaration inside each group.

Comment: If anybody else is wondering what the difference was:

`diff /tmp/original.yml /tmp/test.yml
0a1
> ---
`

(But my problem was actually that I had `hosts.yml` and an older version in `hosts` and it uses `hosts` without any params)

Answer (score 3):

Given the inventory (and the *group_vars*)

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    server_group1:
      hosts:
        host1: {}
    server_group2:
      children:
        app1:
          hosts:
            host2:
              app1: &id001
                name1: value1
                name2: value2
              app2: &id002
                name1: value11
                name2: value22
            host3:
              app1: *id001
              app2: *id002
        app2:
          hosts:
            host4:
              app1: *id001
              app2: *id002
            host5:
              app1: *id001
              app2: *id002
    ungrouped: {}
```

---

```
'hostvars[0].name1' The error was: 'name1' is undefined
```

Q: ***"Where am I going wrong?"***

A: `name1` is an attribute of the dictionary `app1` or `app2`. It must be referenced either `app1.name1` or `app2.name1`. In addition to this, `hostvars` is a dictionary, not an array. `hostvars[0]` does not exist. An attribute in a dictionary must be referenced by a key. For example,

```yaml
  my_keys: "{{ hostvars.keys() }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_keys: [host1, host2, host3, host4, host5]
```

You can use the keys in a loop. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[item].app1.name1 }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      when: item in groups.app1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[item].app2.name1 }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      when: item in groups.app2
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [host2] => (item=host1) 
ok: [host2] => (item=host2) => 
  msg: value1
ok: [host2] => (item=host3) => 
  msg: value1
skipping: [host2] => (item=host4) 
skipping: [host2] => (item=host5) 

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [host2] => (item=host1) 
skipping: [host2] => (item=host2) 
skipping: [host2] => (item=host3) 
ok: [host2] => (item=host4) => 
  msg: value11
ok: [host2] => (item=host5) => 
  msg: value11
```

Optionally use *json_query* to create the list of the keys

```yaml
  my_keys: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|json_query('[].key') }}"
```

---

---

The simplified version of the debug tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].app1.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].app2.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app2
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: value1
skipping: [host4]
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: value1
skipping: [host5]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [host2]
skipping: [host3]
ok: [host4] => 
  msg: value11
ok: [host5] => 
  msg: value11
```

---

In fact, addressing `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` is not necessary. The simplified tasks below give the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ app1.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ app2.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: server_group2

  vars:

    my_keys: "{{ hostvars.keys() }}"

  tasks:

    - block:

        - debug:
            var: hostvars[0]

        - debug:
            var: my_keys|to_yaml

        - debug:
            msg: "{{ hostvars[item].app1.name1 }}"
          loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
          when: item in groups.app1
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ hostvars[item].app2.name1 }}"
          loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
          when: item in groups.app2

      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].app1.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].app2.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app2

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ app1.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ app2.name1 }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups.app2
```

Comment: I kind of realize that. If you could be so kind as to enlighten me of the correct way to access the host's variables?

Comment: Sure. I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you, soo much! Is it possible to go a step further? I would like to read the app1 and app2 off variables. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: ALso, using keys() function in a loop: is giving me this error:

```Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: KeysView({...```

Comment: You're welcome! Open new question(s) and attach  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, I used this instead of keys(): ``
loop: "{{ lookup('dict', hostvars[inventory_hostname]) }}" ``
Meanwhile I am continuing looking for the correct solution for this question.

Comment: Use ``hostvars.keys()|list``. See [Dictionary Views](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_python_version.html#dictionary-views).